# Adding edit role for a service account to an individual Cloud Spanner database

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

How can I add a role for edit permissions to my service account to an individual Cloud Spanner database in my project, without granting it for any others.

Is this possible from console.cloud.google.com?

Answer (score 2):

Roles for Cloud Spanner can be applied to individual databases in a project.

To do this in, select the database you want in the Cloud Spanner table, the click the 'Permissions' button. From here you can add your service accounts email address to assign in the appropriate role.

You can assign overall roles for Cloud Spanner in the in the Cloud console's general IAM page using the following steps:

1. Go to the IAM page
2. On your service account, open the `Role(s)` drop down
3. Expand the `Cloud Spanner` sub menu
4. Select `Cloud Spanner Database User`

The `Cloud Spanner Database User` gives you read/write access, which is what I believe you want with 'edit'

> Access to read, query, write and view and change the schema of Cloud Spanner databases

Comment: Thank you, So it is added to all the database but I want to add choosen... Is it possible?

Comment: viewer vs "cloud spanner viewer" - what is difference?